# Do you need to change the target binary version for CodePush before you make any changes you want included in that version?

Tags: version, code-push, react-native-code-push

Ok, so this might seems obvious but I need to be extra sure and can't find a clear answer anywhere (maybe because it's obvious). Do you need to change the target binary version for CodePush before you make any changes you want included in that version? So, in your commit history the first commit would be the target binary version change, and then anything after that would apply to that target binary version only? Example:

```
Commit History:

Make native changes <- will only be applied to 7.0.0
Update target binary version to 7.0.0 (corresponds to a new binary on the App Store)
Fix bug <- last commit applied to version 6.2.0
```

This makes sense to me but when I did it while I was training, the person training me had me do the native changes first and then change the target binary version so the above looked like this:

```
Commit History:

Update target binary version to 7.0.0 (corresponds to a new binary on the App Store)
Make native changes <- we only want these to be applied to 7.0.0
Fix bug <- last commit we want applied to version 6.2.0
```

Looking at this now, it really doesn't make sense, but it seemed to work and be fine at the time so now I'm unsure. It's also possible there weren't actually any native changes so that's why it was fine, but I don't think they would have taught me this way if it was wrong. Many thanks for any clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the answer is that yes, you do need to commit the target binary version change BEFORE the changes you want to appear in that version. I was thinking maybe CodePush looked at the entire repo as one thing, so it wouldn't matter whether the target binary was changed before or after the other changes, just that it WAS changed, and CodePush would default to the most recent version.